# model.predictProbabilities() for LogisticRegression in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I'm running a multi-class **Logistic Regression (withLBFGS)** with Spark 1.6.

given **x** and possible labels **{1.0,2.0,3.0}** 
the final model will **only** output what is the best prediction, say **2.0**.

If I'm interested to know what was the second best prediction, say **3.0**, how could I retrieve that information?

In NaiveBayes I would use the model.predictProbabilities() function which for each sample would output a vector with all the probabilities for each possible outcome.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do logistic regression in Spark: `spark.ml` and `spark.mllib`.

With DataFrames you can use `spark.ml`:

```
import org.apache.spark
import sqlContext.implicits._

def p(label: Double, a: Double, b: Double) =
  new spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint(
    label, new spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector(Array(a, b)))

val data = sc.parallelize(Seq(p(1.0, 0.0, 0.5), p(0.0, 0.5, 1.0)))
val df = data.toDF

val model = new spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression().fit(df)
model.transform(df).show
```

You get the raw predictions and probabilities:

```
+-----+---------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|label| features|       rawPrediction|         probability|prediction|
+-----+---------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|  1.0|[0.0,0.5]|[-19.037302860930...|[5.39764620520461...|       1.0|
|  0.0|[0.5,1.0]|[18.9861466274786...|[0.99999999431904...|       0.0|
+-----+---------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

With RDDs you can use `spark.mllib`:

```
val model = new spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().run(data)
```

This model does not expose the raw predictions and probabilities. You can take a look at [`predictPoint`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegression.scala#L113). It multiplies the vectors and picks the class with the highest prediction. The weights are publicly accessible, so you could copy that algorithm and save the predictions instead of just returning the highest one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although, Im struggling with understanding how to use the ProbabilisticClassificationModel.


1) Im not sure LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS is a subclass of ProbabilisticClassificationModel.


2) There is no example online for how to use ProbabilisticClassificationModel


3) What would be the dataframe to pass to the transform function? The training set I used for the LogisticRegression?


Sorry for the big confusion.

Comment: You're right, this is not at all obvious. I'll come back with a full example in a few hours!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I fell asleep :). So it looks like there are two classes called `LogisticRegressionModel`, one in `spark.ml` and one in `spark.mllib`. Only the first one gives you the raw predictions. I've rewritten the answer to explain this. It looks easiest to just use `spark.ml`, but if you are okay with copying a bit of code from Spark, you can also do it with `spark.mllib`.

Comment: @DanielDarabos Can you please tell what is the meaning of rawPrediction column here and also how do we know which probability belongs to which class? Thanks

Comment: rawPrediction is before the softmax. (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.scala#L832) The probabilities are in the same order as the classes.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestions from @Daniel Darabos:

1. I tried to use the LogisticRegression function from **ml** instead of **mllib**
   Unfortunately it doesn't support the multi-class logistic regression but only the binary one.
2. I took a look at [PredictedPoint](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegression.scala#L113)
   and modified it so that it prints all the probabilities for each class. Here it is what it looks like:

```scala
    def predictPointForMulticlass(featurizedVector:Vector,weightsArray:Vector,intercept:Double,numClasses:Int,numFeatures:Int) : Seq[(String, Double)] = {

        val weightsArraySize = weightsArray.size
        val dataWithBiasSize = weightsArraySize / (numClasses - 1)
        val withBias = false

        var bestClass = 0
        var maxMargin = 0.0
        var margins = new Array[Double](numClasses - 1)
        var temp_marginMap = new HashMap[Int, Double]()
        var res = new HashMap[Int, Double]()

        (0 until numClasses - 1).foreach { i =>
          var margin = 0.0
          var index = 0
          featurizedVector.toArray.foreach(value => {
            if (value != 0.0) {
              margin += value * weightsArray((i * dataWithBiasSize) + index)
            }
            index += 1
          }
          )
        // Intercept is required to be added into margin.
        if (withBias) {
            margin += weightsArray((i * dataWithBiasSize) + featurizedVector.size)
        }
        val prob = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-margin))
        margins(i) = margin

        temp_marginMap += (i -> margin)

        if(margin > maxMargin) {
            maxMargin = margin
            bestClass = i + 1
          }
        }

        for ((k,v) <- temp_marginMap){
          val calc =probCalc(maxMargin,v)
          res += (k -> calc)
        }

      return res
    }
```

where probCalc() is simply defined as:

```
      def probCalc(maxMargin:Double,margin:Double) :Double ={
        val res = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-(margin - maxMargin)))
        res
      }
```

I'm returning a Hashmap[Int, Double] but that can be changed as you wish.

Hopefully this helps!